# Questions about data formatting using UiApp and google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide. As background, I built a simple UiApp using GAS that I use to populate a google spreadsheet and a calendar with entries about events including time, date, location, etc. I've had it working for awhile but I want to keep improving it and I have a few questions about format and functionality.

1.) I now want the script to copy the information to a second spreadsheet, I've established how to do this, but the second spreadsheet already has some columns in use that I don't want to override and I don't want to just place the info from this Ui into the first 'X' number of columns, is there any easy way to essentially "copy these 5 columns to the first then skip and column and bring in the rest". Here is the code I have for the copy action right now:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 20).setValues([[new Date(), eventTitle, eventDateFrom, eventStartTimeb, eventEndTimeb, eventLocationName, eventLocationCity,eventActivity, eventLeadContact, eventNSLContact, eventContactAttending, eventDepartment, eventStaff, eventMaterials, eventCost, eventIncentive, eventMSTarget, eventSolar, eventNotes,eventRegion]]);
```

Also, in the same vein as this question, I've been wondering if it is possible to write something that will choose when an entry is copied to the second spreadsheet based on the value of one of the elements. For example, if eventStaff=0 or is blank, the script will copy the designated information to first spreadsheet but not the second.

2.) Date format: I added two listboxes for to capture event time start and event time end and I would like them to show up in the spreadsheet formatted as 00:00 AM/PM, but have only accomplished to get 00:00:00 or whole number so far.

3.) Using multiple elements to fill the location and events portion of calendar entries. This script works to create a basic event with start/end time and a title, but I'd like to use some of the information to fill in the location and description of an event. Is there a way for me to do this or do I need to concatenate those fields into one in able to enter them in the event creation. Current event creation code:

```
 cal.createEvent(eventTitle,eventDateFrom,eventDateTo);
```

Sorry for the wall of text, if any clarification/additional code sample is needed just ask. Thank you in advance for any help/insight you might be able to provide.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't be offended but I'm afraid your questions are more general programming question than GAS question, by formulating the question you almost answer it by yourself (question 1).
As for question 2, have a look to [Utilities.formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_utilities?hl=fr-FR#formatDate) and you'll get what you want, see also [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).
Question 3: see [CalendarApp documentation, createEvent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_calendarapp?hl=fr-FR#createEvent), there is a set of optional arguments that suits your needs. - best regards,

Comment: Thank you for replying, I was worried that my post was too general, but I posted a similar but unrelated question another time and a mod tagged it with GAS. Thank you for the helpful links!